# DocuSign Rest API - Downloading Completed Document after using multiple CompositeTemplates

Tags: java, rest, docusignapi

I'm trying to download completed document(s) from a Docusign  Envelope sing the below code:

`byte[] fileData = envelopesApi.getDocument(accountId, envelopeId, documentId);`

However, I think the problem lies with how I'm sending the documents in compositeTemplates that make up the envelope. I'm assigning both documents an ID that corresponds to a custom POJO object's ID in my application. The above `envelopesApi.getDocument(accountId, envelopeId, documentId)` code worked great until I implemented the compositeTemplate design describe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42591749/docusign-java-rest-api-combining-anchor-tagged-custom-file-and-pdf-form-field).

Do I need to use a different ID for each document?

Should I be using a different API call to get back these documents? There will likely be more than two compositeTemplates in the future. So I'll need a way to download all documents in a given envelope.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The document Id's can be retrieved using the [listEnvelopeDocuments](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeDocuments/list/) api.

Sample Json Response

```
{
  "envelopeId": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "envelopeDocuments": [
    {
      "documentId": "1",
      "name": "document one",
      "type": "content",
    },
    {
      "documentId": "2",
      "name": "document two",
      "type": "content",
    },
    {
      "documentId": "certificate",
      "name": "Summary",
      "type": "summary",
    }
  ]
}
```

You can then download the documents by passing the correct documentId to the [getEnvelopeDocument](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeDocuments/get/) api.

The documentId also takes two special values

- **combined** Retrieve a PDF that contains the combined content of all documents and the certificate.
- **archive**  Retrieve a ZIP archive that contains all of the PDF documents, the certificate, and any .WAV files used for voice authentication.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was trying to use  the Object Oriented version (depicted in the link in the question), rather than just building GET requests; however, I was not able to find a way to return the "combined" PDFs. So I was was forced to refactor. Again, thanks for the help