# How to send to multiple recipients using Docusign Java API?

Tags: docusignapi

I have a Docusign template with role names "Applicant". and "Co-applicant". On the signature page there's a tab for each of them to sign.

I'm trying to use the Java API to send a document to both recipients, one after the other, so they can each sign in their respective tab, but I'm running into several problems.

Below is my code.  The problems I am having are as follows:

1) If I use the actual role names in the .setRoleName calls, I get a TAB_REFERS_TO_MISSING_DOCUMENT error when it gets to the createEnvelope line.

2) If I use new role names (e.g., "Applicant1" and "Co-applicant1"), the email gets sent to the Applicant, who has access to BOTH signing fields.  When they sign, the document is completed, and it never gets to the Co-applicant.

I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong.  Would anyone who can, be so kind as to help me out?  Thank you!

```
<Initializations>
envDef = new EnvelopeDefinition();
CompositeTemplate tCompositeTemplate = new CompositeTemplate();
Document document = new Document();

tCompositeTemplate.setDocument(document);
tCompositeTemplate.getDocument().setDocumentBase64(Base64.encodeBase64String(fileBytes));
tCompositeTemplate.getDocument().setName("<docName>");
tCompositeTemplate.getDocument().setDocumentId(1);
tCompositeTemplate.getDocument().setTransformPdfFields("true");
tCompositeTemplate.getDocument().setFileExtension("pdf");

java.util.List<Document> docs = new ArrayList<Document>();
docs.add(tCompositeTemplate.getDocument());
envDef.setDocuments(docs);

Signer signerApp = new Signer();
signerApp.setEmail("<appEmail>");
signerApp.setName("<appName>");
signerApp.setRecipientId("1");
signerApp.setRoutingOrder("1");

Signer signerCoapp = new Signer();
signerCoapp.setEmail("<coappEmail>");
signerCoapp.setName("<coappName>");
signerCoapp.setRecipientId("2");
signerCoapp.setRoutingOrder("2");

java.util.List<SignHere> signHereTabs = new ArrayList<SignHere>();

SignHere signHereApp = new SignHere();
signHereApp.setDocumentId(tCompositeTemplate.getDocument().getDocumentId());
signHereApp.setRecipientId("1");
signHereApp.setTabLabel("\\*primary_app_sig_2_DocuSignSignHere");
signHereTabs.add(signHereApp);

SignHere signHereCoapp = new SignHere();
signHereCoapp.setDocumentId(tCompositeTemplate.getDocument().getDocumentId());
signHereCoapp.setRecipientId("2");
signHereCoapp.setTabLabel("\\*co_app_sig_2_DocuSignSignHere");
signHereTabs.add(signHereCoapp);

Tabs tabs = new Tabs();
tabs.setSignHereTabs(signHereTabs);
signerApp.setTabs(tabs);
signerCoapp.setTabs(tabs);

tRoleApp = new TemplateRole();
tRoleApp.setEmail("<Email>");
tRoleApp.setName("<Name>");
tRoleApp.setRoleName("Applicant");

tRoleCoApp= new TemplateRole();
tRoleCoApp.setEmail("<Email>");
tRoleCoApp.setName("<Name>");
tRoleCoApp.setRoleName("Co-applicant");

java.util.List<TemplateRole> rolesList = new ArrayList<>();
rolesList.add(tRoleApp);
rolesList.add(tRoleCoApp);
envDef.setTemplateId("<templateID>");
envDef.setTemplateRoles(rolesList);

envDef.getTemplateRoles().get(0).setTabs(new Tabs());
envDef.getTemplateRoles().get(0).getTabs().setSignHereTabs(new ArrayList<SignHere>());
envDef.getTemplateRoles().get(0).getTabs().getSignHereTabs().add(signHereApp);    

envDef.getTemplateRoles().get(1).setTabs(new Tabs());
envDef.getTemplateRoles().get(1).getTabs().setSignHereTabs(new ArrayList<SignHere>());
envDef.getTemplateRoles().get(1).getTabs().getSignHereTabs().add(signHereCoapp);

EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi();
envelopeSummary = envelopesApi.createEnvelope(<"acctID">, envDef);
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the wording of your post, it sounds like the template that you've created via the DocuSign web UI already contains the document, tabs, and recipient role info (e.g., recipient role names and routing order). If that's the case, then you don't need to specify document and tab info as part of the `Create Envelope` API request -- you only need to specify the TEMPLATE_ID and the info for each recipient (role name, name, and email). The following code example illustrates this approach.

```
// create a new envelope definition object 
EnvelopeDefinition envDef = new EnvelopeDefinition();

// specify the ID of the template that contains the document, recipient roles, tabs, etc.
envDef.setTemplateId("TEMPLATE_ID");

// specify info for first recipient (applicant)
TemplateRole tRole1 = new TemplateRole();
tRole1.setRoleName("Applicant");
tRole1.setName("APPLICANT_NAME");
tRole1.setEmail("APPLICANT_EMAIL");

// specify info for second recipient (co-applicant)
TemplateRole tRole2 = new TemplateRole();
tRole2.setRoleName("Co-applicant");
tRole2.setName("CO-APPLICANT_NAME");
tRole2.setEmail("CO-APPLICANT_EMAIL");

// add recipient info to the envelope definition
java.util.List<TemplateRole> templateRolesList = new java.util.ArrayList<TemplateRole>();
templateRolesList.add(tRole1);
templateRolesList.add(tRole2);
envDef.setTemplateRoles(templateRolesList);

// set status to "sent" so that the Envelope will be sent when the API request is issued
envDef.setStatus("sent");

// issue the Create Envelope API request to create/send the Envelope
EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi(apiClient);
EnvelopeSummary envelopeSummary = envelopesApi.createEnvelope(accountId, envDef);
```

(If I've misunderstood your scenario and there *is* a reason that you need to specify document and tab info in the `Create Envelope` request, add a comment on this answer and I'll provide info about how to achieve that.)

Comment: Thank you!

The template does have the roles and the tabs, but the specific document will need to change.  What we're sending are contracts that have a standard signature page, but differing specifics.

Comment: If your goal is for the document that your template contains to be replaced at run-time with the document your API request specifies, then the `Document` object needs to be added to the `CompositeTemplate` object (not to the `EnvelopeDefinition` object as your code is doing).  Also, your `CompositeTemplate` object needs to specify an `InlineTemplate` that contains the recipient and tab info.  For a code example that shows these things, see the answer to this SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42591749/docusign-java-rest-api-combining-anchor-tagged-custom-file-and-pdf-form-field.

Comment: *Note:* the SO answer I linked to in my prior comment addresses a scenario that's more complex than yours (so you don't need all the code that the answer contains).  Just pay attention to how the code is assembling the document, recipients, and tabs to form the `CompositeTemplate` object (which is then added to the `EnvelopeDefinition` object before creating/sending the envelope).

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you so much.  With a few tweaks I am now seeing the expected behavior.

Comment: Oh.  Except now I have another issue, which is the finalized document doesn't have the sig.  The second signer sees the first signer's sig, but once that's done and anyone views the completed documents, the sigs are gone.  Do I open a new question for that if I can't figure out why or continue here?  Sorry, I'm new to Stack Overflow.

Comment: I’d suggest you create a new post about that issue, and be sure to include the code that’s giving that result.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing two DocuSign design or strategy patterns, one is `Composite Template` and another is `TemplateRole`. You should not mix both in same EnvelopeDefinition Call. `CompositeTemplate` is a recommended design approach as it covers all the scenarios which are not covered in TemplateRole. For instance, if you have a scenario where you need to add multiple DS Server Templates or mix of ServerTemplate and a runtime document in a single envelope, then your only solution is Composite Template. So always create a solution with `Composite Template` as it is most robust design pattern and covers all the scenarios.

A Valid example for `Composite Template` will be:

```
<Initializations>
envDef = new EnvelopeDefinition();
CompositeTemplate tCompositeTemplate = new CompositeTemplate();

Signer signerApp = new Signer();
signerApp.setEmail("<appEmail>");
signerApp.setName("<appName>");
signerApp.setRecipientId("1");
signerApp.setRoutingOrder("1");
signerApp.setRoleName("Applicant");

Signer signerCoapp = new Signer();
signerCoapp.setEmail("<coappEmail>");
signerCoapp.setName("<coappName>");
signerCoapp.setRecipientId("2");
signerCoapp.setRoutingOrder("2");
signerCoapp.setRoleName("Co-applicant");

//Below code is required if you want to pass a document in the composite
//template, either to replace the document present in the server Template
//or you do not have a server template

Document document = new Document();

tCompositeTemplate.setDocument(document);
tCompositeTemplate.getDocument().setDocumentBase64(Base64.encodeBase64String(fileBytes));
tCompositeTemplate.getDocument().setName("<docName>");
tCompositeTemplate.getDocument().setDocumentId(1);
tCompositeTemplate.getDocument().setTransformPdfFields("true");
tCompositeTemplate.getDocument().setFileExtension("pdf");

java.util.List<SignHere> signHereTabs = new ArrayList<SignHere>();

SignHere signHereApp = new SignHere();
signHereApp.setDocumentId(tCompositeTemplate.getDocument().getDocumentId());
signHereApp.setRecipientId("1");
signHereApp.setTabLabel("\\*primary_app_sig_2_DocuSignSignHere");
signHereTabs.add(signHereApp);

SignHere signHereCoapp = new SignHere();
signHereCoapp.setDocumentId(tCompositeTemplate.getDocument().getDocumentId());
signHereCoapp.setRecipientId("2");
signHereCoapp.setTabLabel("\\*co_app_sig_2_DocuSignSignHere");
signHereTabs.add(signHereCoapp);

Tabs tabs = new Tabs();
tabs.setSignHereTabs(signHereTabs);
signerApp.setTabs(tabs);
signerCoapp.setTabs(tabs);

Recipients recipients = new Recipients();

List<Signer> signers = new ArrayList<Signer>();
signers.add(signerApp);
signers.add(signerCoapp);

recipients.setSigners(signers);

InlineTemplate inlineTemplate = new InlineTemplate();
inlineTemplate.setRecipients(recipients);
inlineTemplate.setSequence("2");

List<InlineTemplate> inlineTemplateList = new ArrayList<InlineTemplate>();
inlineTemplateList.add(inlineTemplate);
tCompositeTemplate.setInlineTemplates(inlineTemplateList);


//Below ServerTemplate is required if you have server template
//and all the signer tabs are already added in the server template
ServerTemplate serverTemplate = new ServerTemplate();
serverTemplate.setSequence("1");
serverTemplate.setTemplateId("SERVER_TEMPLATE_ID");

List<ServerTemplate> serverTemplateList = new ArrayList<ServerTemplate>();
serverTemplateList.add(serverTemplate);
tCompositeTemplate.setServerTemplates(serverTemplateList);
//Adding ServerTemplate to compositeTemplate finishes here

List<CompositeTemplate> compositeTemplateList = new ArrayList<CompositeTemplate>();
compositeTemplateList.add(tCompositeTemplate);

envDef.setCompositeTemplates(compositeTemplateList);

EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi();
envelopeSummary = envelopesApi.createEnvelope(<"acctID">, envDef);
```

Comment: Thank you!  I had already made a bunch of changes based on what Kim said, but hadn't realized the Template Roles were no longer needed; they were a remnant from when I thought the runtime document overwrote the template.  This helped me clean up my code by removing those unnecessary assignments.